# How can to run a visual c++ exe from keyboard shortcut?

Tags: windows, visual-studio

When I create a shortcut to my exe (which I built from VS2008 on Win7 x64) and set a keyboard shortcut from the properties dialog, it doesn't launch when I press the key combination. It works for other programs which I have installed on the PC. Is there something additional we need to do, like enter a registry setting or something?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is your shortcut on the Desktop or Start Menu? Keyboard shortcuts only work if the file shortcut is either on the Desktop or Start Menu, not from regular Explorer folders.

Comment: ahh. That was the issue. It works from the desktop. It was still in my build folder. Is there a way to get it to work from a different folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keyboard shortcuts only work if the file shortcut is either on the Desktop or Start Menu, not from regular Explorer folders.

Assigning global hotkeys to programs isn't possible without a third-party application as far as I know. There's a similar question on [Superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/110397/reliable-custom-windows-shortcut-keys), where the solution is either a AutoHotKey script (which runs in background):

```
;Windows-Key + P
#P::
run D:\Workspace\My\Build\Directory\bin\application.exe
return
```

or an external application like [PS Hot Launch](http://www.pssoftlab.com/pshl_info.phtml).

Other than that might placing the shortcut in the Start Menu probably the least intrusive solution, if you don't want an icon on your Desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Simple go to Start->All Programs
Locate visual c++ 2008 shortcut
Go to its properties assign short cut keys there. For example- ctr+alt+v

Go to desktop and try that shortcut. It would work